# Binary search algorithm without repeats

Tags: c#, math, logic, biginteger

I'm trying to write a function that will allow a the processing of all of the numbers from 0-n in a binary search pattern, without repeats.

Here's an example of what I'm aiming for:

```
get(bigint max, bigint point)

get(10000, 0) = 0   //start
get(10000, 1) = 10000   //end

get(10000, 2) = 5000    //middle

get(10000, 3) = 2500    //(max/4) * 1
// Skip 500 as we've already done that one
get(10000, 4) = 7500    //(max/4) * 3

get(10000, 5) = 1250    //(max/8) * 1
// Skip 250 as we've already done it
get(10000, 6) = 3750    //(max/8) * 3
// Skip 500 as we've already done that one
get(10000, 7) = 6250    //(max/8) * 5
// Skip 750 as we've already done that one
get(10000, 8) = 8750    //(max/8) * 7
```

I think that there's a heuristic to be had in that all of the multipliers are odd, and by using powers of 2 as the divisor.

How can I do this most efficiently, given that nearly all the numbers in play will be BigIntegers?

Comment: I'm extremely confused. Is this function returning the value at the theoretical given index (point?) of an array if the value at each index in the array was equal to what order that index would be checked in an arbitrary binary search algorithm? Or maybe you're dealing with a binary tree instead of an array since `point` 1 holds the value (right?) 10000? Or is it returning the order in which indices are checked? At any rate, it seems like this would at least partly rely on your implementation of the binary search algorithm.

Comment: How is this a binary search algorithm?  The point of binary search is that if you check the item at index 5000 and it is smaller than the item you're looking for, you don't need to look at items 0 through 4999.  Or, if it's bigger, you don't need to look at items 5001 through 10000.  So in a true binary search, your next step would be to look at either index 2500 or 7500, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

here is an algorithm (pseudocode)

```
function get(max, point)
  if point == 0 then 
    return 0
  if point == 1 then
    return max
  x = 2*point-1
  y = high_power_of_two(x)  // e.g., high_power_of_two(13) == 8
  return (x-y)*(max/y)
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking that high_power_of_two will return the next highest power of two, or are there standard Math functions to do this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know C#, but this function must be very cheap (in CPU ticks) and easily implementing in every programming environment.

Comment: That's fine, I can implement high_power_of_two(x) myself, I just need to be sure that I understand what it does, in pseudocode is fine.